# How to match and replace pattern without regex?

Tags: ruby, string, replace

I was recently asked this in an interview and was figuring out a way to do this without using regex in Ruby as I was told it would be a bonus if you can solve it without using regex.

Question: Assume that the hash has 1 million key, value pairs and we have to be able to sub the variables in the string that are between `% %` this pattern. How would I be able to do this without regex.

We have a string `str = "%greet%! Hi there, %var_1% that can be any other %var_2% injected to the %var_3%. Nice!, goodbye)"`

we have a hash called `dict = { greet: 'Hi there', var_1: 'FIRST VARIABLE', var_2: 'values', var_3: 'string', }`

This was my solution:

```
def template(str, dict)
  vars = value.scan(/%(.*?)%/).flatten
  vars.each do |var|
    value = value.gsub("%#{var}%", dict[var.to_sym])
  end
  value
end
```

Comment: Still using a regular expression, but byb passing a block to `#gsub` this can be a "one-liner": `str.gsub(/%[^%]+%/) { |m| dict[m[1..-2].to_sym] }`

Comment: If you are not asking for a regex solution, no need to tag the question with this tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach:

First, split the string on `'%'`:

```
str = "%greet%! Hi there, %var_1% that can be any other %var_2% injected to the %var_3%. Nice!, goodbye)"
chunks = str.split('%')
```

Now we can assume given the way the problem has been specified, that every other "chunk" will be a key to replace. Iterating with the index will make that easier to figure out.

```
chunks.each_with_index { |c, i| chunks[i] = (i.even? ? c : dict[c.to_sym]) }.join
```

Result:

```
"Hi there! Hi there, FIRST VARIABLE that can be any other values injected to the string. Nice!, goodbye)"
```

Note: this does *not* handle malformed input well at all.

Answer (score 2):

There are *many* ways to solve this, but you will probably need some kind of [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and / or [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) if you don't want to use built-in pattern matching.

Let's keep it very simple and say that your string's content falls into two categories: *text* and *variable* which are *separated* by `%`, e.g. (you could also think of the variables being *enclosed* by `%`, but that's harder to implement)

```
str = "Hello %name%, hope to see you %when%!"
#      TTTTTT VVVV TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT VVVV T
```

As you can see, the categories are alternating. We can utilize this and write a little helper method that turns a string into a list of `[type, value]` pairs, something like this:

```
def each_part(str)
  return enum_for(__method__, str) unless block_given?

  type = [:text, :var].cycle
  buf = ''

  str.each_char do |char|
    if char != '%'
      buf << char
    else
      yield type.next, buf
      buf = ''
    end
  end
  yield type.next, buf
end
```

It starts by defining an enumerator that will [`cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Array.html#cycle-method) between the two types and an empty buffer. It will then read [`each_char`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#each_char-method) from the string. If the char is not `%`, it will just append it to the buffer and keep reading. Once it encounters a `%`, it will `yield` the current buffer along with the type and start a new buffer ([`next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerator.html#next-method) will also switch the `type`). After the loop ends, it will `yield` once more to output the remaining characters.

It outputs this kind of data:

```
each_part(str).to_a
#=> [[:text, "Hello "],
#    [:var, "name"],
#    [:text, ", hope to see you "],
#    [:var, "when"],
#    [:text, "!"]]
```

We can use this to convert the string:

```
dict = { name: 'Tom', when: 'soon' }

output = ''
each_part(str) do |type, value|
  case type
  when :text
    output << value
  when :var
    output << dict[value.to_sym]
  end
end
p output
#=> "Hello Tom, hope to see you soon!"
```

You could of course combine parsing and evaluation, but I like the separation. An full-fledged parser might involve even more steps.